# Spring Reactive processing Server Side Events

Tags: spring-webflux

How to recieve streaming data via Server Side Events `Content-Type: text/event-stream` using Spring Flux features? Is it possible to handle such responses with WebClient?

Source end-point:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<CurrencyStats> get() {
    return getStream();
}
```

I tried to get data that way, but it seems to be wrong.

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create("http://example.com");
        return webClient
                .get()
                .uri("/sse")
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(String.class).doOnNext(
                        string -> {
                            // print that string
                        }
                );
```

Answer (score 0):

That is what i needed:

```
WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(url);
        Flux<Map> alerts = webClient.get()
                .uri("/sse")
                .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Map.class)
                .checkpoint().doOnNext(
                        s -> {
                            logger.log(Level.ERROR, s);
                        }
                );
```